# Jupyter Notebook Launch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, cobra

I am a very new user in phyton and anaconda. Today I found an error message when I wanted to open Jupyter notebook in anaconda.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 43, in 
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in 
from .environment import Environment
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in 
from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in 
from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in 
from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thank you very much in advance for your kind help.

Regards,
Deper

I hope I can get some suggestions to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Open the Anaconda Prompt (or any terminal) and run the following command to update the markupsafe package:

```
conda update markupsafe
```

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: Unfortunetaly, not solved yet. Some errors always appeared. I do not know why.